# pip install vulkan

Tags: python, python3, vulkan

I tried to install the python wrapper to Vulkan using the command (as is instructed in this [website](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/vulkan)):

```
pip install vulkan
```

However, the installation failed. Error given below.

What must I do to achieve a successful  installation?

My system is installed with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, 4.8.0-44-generic, gcc, gcc-5, libgcc-5-dev:amd64.

```
$ pip install vulkan
Collecting vulkan
  Using cached vulkan-1.3.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    c/_cffi_backend.c:2:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 118, in _compile
        extra_postargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 909, in spawn
        spawn(cmd, dry_run=self.dry_run)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/spawn.py", line 36, in spawn
        _spawn_posix(cmd, search_path, dry_run=dry_run)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/spawn.py", line 159, in _spawn_posix
        % (cmd, exit_status))
    distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 161, in run
        cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 147, in call_command
        self.run_command(cmdname)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install_lib.py", line 23, in run
        self.build()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/install_lib.py", line 109, in build
        self.run_command('build_ext')
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 49, in run
        _build_ext.run(self)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 338, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 447, in build_extensions
        self._build_extensions_serial()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 472, in _build_extensions_serial
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 174, in build_extension
        _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 532, in build_extension
        depends=ext.depends)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 574, in compile
        self._compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 120, in _compile
        raise CompileError(msg)
    distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
        yield saved
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
        yield
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 243, in run_setup
        DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 273, in run
        return func()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 242, in runner
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 46, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "/tmp/easy_install-yozcy3gj/cffi-1.10.0/setup.py", line 232, in <module>
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 163, in setup
        raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
    SystemExit: error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1087, in run_setup
        run_setup(setup_script, args)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 246, in run_setup
        raise
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
        yield
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
        saved_exc.resume()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
        six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/six.py", line 685, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
        yield saved
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
        yield
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 243, in run_setup
        DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 273, in run
        return func()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 242, in runner
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 46, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "/tmp/easy_install-yozcy3gj/cffi-1.10.0/setup.py", line 232, in <module>
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 163, in setup
        raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
    SystemExit: error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-n5qfo287/vulkan/setup.py", line 28, in <module>
        cffi_modules=["_cffi_build/vulkan_build.py:ffi"]
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 269, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 313, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 826, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1092, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1104, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 380, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 663, in easy_install
        return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 693, in install_item
        dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 873, in install_eggs
        return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1101, in build_and_install
        self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1089, in run_setup
        raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-n5qfo287/vulkan/
```

**Updated: pip installation commands**

I installed pip and pip3 using these commands:

```
wget -v https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -O get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
pip install -U pip
```

I checked my installation using these commands

```
python3 -c "import pip; print(pip.__version__)"
python2 -c "import pip; print(pip.__version__)"
```

Comment: `fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory` - did you install the `python-dev` package?

Comment: @steeldriver Nope. Just installed it. But still got the same error msgs.

Comment: Try a new terminal!

Comment: I just noticed all the messages refer to python3 - is your pip aliased to pip3 or somesuch?

Comment: @George I tried issuing the command in a new terminal and got the same error. Rebooted too and got the same error.

Comment: @steeldriver I have updated my question with the pip installation commands that I had used. This was to get the latest pip version. Thus I think the answer to your question is  yes. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the above error, I first installed these packages

```
sudo apt-get install python3.5-dev libpython3.5
```

When I ran pip install vulkan, I got another error:

```
error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pycparser': Permission denied
```

The installation failed because it wanted access permission to write to a root level directory. This was not possible with a normal user permission.

I tried `sudo pip install vulkan` but was told `sudo: pip3: command not found`

I read other sites the explained it was not a good practice to install pip for sudo as it can break the package installation-management system. However, with the above error message, I thought I did not have a choice if I wanted vulkan installed. I then proceeded to install python3-pip for sudo using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip

The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpython3-dev python-pip-whl python3-dev python3-pip python3-wheel
```

I ran `sudo pip3 install vulkan` and finally got:

```
  Running setup.py install for pycparser ... done
  Running setup.py install for vulkan ... done
Successfully installed cffi-1.10.0 pycparser-2.17 vulkan-1.3.0
```

To verify, I ran these commands and got a confirmation:

```
$ pip list --format=legacy | grep vulkan
vulkan (1.3.0)
$ pip3 list --format=legacy | grep vulkan
vulkan (1.3.0)
```

**Notes:**

1. I found `sudo find $HOME -name 'pip' -print` to be very useful. It
   lists all locations of pip in a user's directory. Basically, the
   command `pip install -U pip` mentioned in my question installed pip in

   ```
   ~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip
   ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip
   ~/.local/bin/pip
   ```
2. This is where things becomes unclear to me (I would appreciate help to understand). Why did `pip install vulkan` wrote into `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/` instead of `~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/`? I had thought that if I (a user) activated pip, the pip installation should have been confined to my home directory and not have to write into a root level directory.